# Angular 'loading' while waiting for API in child component

Tags: angular, rest, api, loading

So I have a Dashboard component that retrieves data from various API's, and passes it as `@Input()` marketData, to an Infobox container which shows the data.

I would like to show a loading symbol while waiting for this data.

I have tried using an `*ngIf` else block, but that extremely slowed down the application and made it unable to change navigation while waiting for the data.

dashboard.component.ts

```js
    const henryHubResponse = await this.marketDataService.getHenryHub().toPromise();
      let henryHub = {
        date: this.getDateEia(henryHubResponse.series[0].data[0][0]),
        price: henryHubResponse.series[0].data[0][1].toFixed(2),
        status: henryHubResponse.series[0].data[0][1] >= henryHubResponse.series[0].data[1][1] ? true : false,
      }

    this.marketData['HENRYHUB'] = henryHub;
```

dashboard-infobox.component.ts

```js
<div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.HENRYHUB">
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        Henry Hub
                    </p>
                    <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.HENRYHUB.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.price }} $/MMBtu
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
                    </p>
                </div>
```

This code doesn't show the ROW until the data is available, so I would like this ROW to be visible at all time, but instead of the 'price' it can show '...' or 'loading'.

I tried this:

```js
<div class="exchange" *ngIf="marketData.HENRYHUB; else elseHENRYHUB">
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        Henry Hub
                    </p>
                    <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.HENRYHUB.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.price }} $/MMBtu
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ marketData.HENRYHUB.date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
                    </p>
                </div>

                <ng-template #else elseHENRYHUB>
                <div class="exchange">
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 30%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        Henry Hub
                    </p>
                    <img matListAvatar [src]="marketData.HENRYHUB.status ? 'assets/img/up.png' : 'assets/img/down.png'" style="width: 20px" />
                    <p style="flex: 0 0 40%; margin-left: 15px;">
                        ... $/MMBtu
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        {{ date | date: 'MMM dd' }}
                    </p>
                </div>
                </ng-template>
```

After using this method the DASHBOARD component became extremely slow.

Comment: See https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-block-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And... if you use the CDK library, the Overlay component, not working? I say this option because you can create a service with this functionality and it's more easy to manager.

For example: https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/11/20/custom-overlays-with-angulars-cdk.html

Example of code (V5): https://github.com/jserra91/first-look-cdk